# $http post not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am using below code to fetch response from server, but I am getting empty JSON response.

```
    $scope.cardNumber='12345';
    var data={cardNumber:$scope.cardNumber};
    data=angular.toJson(data);
    $http.post('xyz_1.json',data,{contentType:'application/json'}).success(function(data,status){
 });
```

When I debug the code it is going to http post and then returning, it is not even hitting the server side where I am checking for request payload and returning the response.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

At server side I am expecting string in request.

Comment: check console..may be your request is not reached to server..there you logged error in console.

Comment: `contentType` not `contentTyepe`

Comment: How can you get an empty response without hitting the server? Also, I doubt your server cares about a header named "contentTyepe". It's useless anyway to set this header and to call angular.toJSON: angular does that for you. What **exactly** do you get as response, in your browser dev tools?

Comment: Hi @PankajParkar : I checked the browser console it is not showing error, it is showing json file with empty response. I also debugged the code from java side where controller is written for checking request but it is not reaching there.

Comment: Should it be `angular.toJson()`, or would `.toJSON()` also work?

Comment: @HanletEscaño : it is angular.toJson()

Comment: @JBNizet : I am getting json file with no response.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Post a screenshot of the whole response. You cannot get something from a http server without receiving a response.

Comment: What is "xyz_1.json" ?

Comment: I have also tried removing content type and passing plain string , but that is also not working

Comment: @JBNizet: Unfortunately, I can post screenshot by tomorrow. but in layman term I can say when i check network tab in console it is showing xyz_1.json  response section as empty

Comment: @iborgav :  xyz_1.json is server side object which I am trying to hit

Comment: The first parameter should be the URL you want to hit - from the docs:
post(url, data, [config]);
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: And what is the status of this response? 200? 400? 404? Something else? What makes you think the request doesn't hit the server, since you are getting a response back? An empty response is still a response.

Comment: @JBNizet : I am getting response 200 status ok, but a java side there is a controller written which will catch this request and return a response, but when I am going in debugging mode it s not reaching that controller.

Comment: @ibograv: First paramemter is url only in my code.

Comment: @user3045179 what if you have a non-existent json file ("sdfsdfsd.json") do you still get an empty array?

Comment: It's clearly a server-side issue. The server is getting the request, and is returning an empty response. Check for a filter intercepting the request before your controller.

Comment: @HanletEscaño : Will check for that thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet : There is a angular interceptor for checking response, will check that